# Azure New-AzResourceGroupDeployment: how to convert json text to -TemplateObject in PowerShel 5.1

Tags: json, azure, powershell, deployment

The `New-AzResourceGroupDeployment`  supports ARM template from `-TemplateObject`. It needs a valid Hashtable value for this TemplateObject option. Document is [there](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azresourcegroupdeployment?view=azps-7.0.0#example-2--use-a-custom-template-object-and-parameter-file-to-create-a-deployment).

In my case, I am running `Windows 10` which has `PowerShell 5.1`. I read the `JSON` file content as `Plain Text` then I can convert it to `PSObject`. But in this PowerShell 5.1 environment, `ConvertFrom-Json` does not support the `-AsHashtable` option so I am not able to convert the PSObject to the required Hashtable.

How can I manually convert my `PSObject` to the `Hashtable` as required by the `New-AzResourceGroupDeployment`  in `PowerShell 5.1`?

I tried this:

```
    $armHashtable71 = ConvertFrom-Json $jsonFileOnline.Content -AsHashtable

    $armPSObjects = ConvertFrom-Json $jsonFileOnline.Content
    $armHashtable51 = @{}
    $armPSObjects.PSObject.Properties | Foreach-Object { $armHashtable51[$_.Name]= $_.Value }
```

Then I do see the difference of the hashtables:

```
[DBG]: PS C:\Users\me> $armHashtable51 


Name                           Value
----                           -----
parameters                     @{buildVersion=; azureSubID=; virtualMachineRG=; virtualMachineName=; virtualMachineSize=; virtualNetworkRG=; virtualNetworkName=; networkInterfaceName=; adminUsername=; adminPassword=}
outputs                        @{adminUsername=}
variables                      @{vnetId=[concat('/subscriptions/',parameters('azureSubID'),'/resourceGroups/',parameters('virtualNetworkRG'),'/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/',parameters('virtualNetworkName…$schema                        http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#
contentVersion                 1.0.0.0
resources                      {@{name=[parameters('networkInterfaceName')]; type=Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces; apiVersion=2021-03-01; location=westus2; dependsOn=System.Object[]; properties=; tags=}, @{name=[par…

[DBG]: PS C:\Users\me> $armHashtable51.parameters


buildVersion         : @{type=string}
azureSubID           : @{type=string}
virtualMachineRG     : @{type=string}
virtualMachineName   : @{type=string}
virtualMachineSize   : @{type=string}
virtualNetworkRG     : @{type=string}
virtualNetworkName   : @{type=string}
networkInterfaceName : @{type=string}
adminUsername        : @{type=string}
adminPassword        : @{type=secureString}


[DBG]: PS C:\Users\me> $armHashtable51.parameters.buildVersion


type  
----  
string

[DBG]: PS C:\Users\me> $armHashtable71


Name                           Value
----                           -----
outputs                        {adminUsername}
parameters                     {virtualMachineName, adminPassword, virtualMachineRG, buildVersion…}
contentVersion                 1.0.0.0
resources                      {[parameters('networkInterfaceName')], [parameters('virtualMachineName')]}
$schema                        http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#
variables                      {vnetName, subnetRef, vnetId}

[DBG]: PS C:\Users\me> $armHashtable71.parameters


Name                           Value
----                           -----
virtualMachineName             {type}
adminPassword                  {type}
virtualMachineRG               {type}
buildVersion                   {type}
adminUsername                  {type}
azureSubID                     {type}
virtualNetworkRG               {type}
virtualNetworkName             {type}
networkInterfaceName           {type}
virtualMachineSize             {type}

[DBG]: PS C:\Users\me> $armHashtable71.parameters.buildVersion


Name                           Value
----                           -----
type                           string
```

How to make this Hashtable (5.1 version) to same Hashtable of the "7.1 version"?

Comment: OK, I workaround this issue by using Deployment Name to support deployment concurrently.

Comment: Hello @Betty, Can you please provide the same workaround as an answer?